# IE not firing input event on deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, input

I'm trying to put some placeholders in a form. They are working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I can't get them to work on IE (I'm testing this with IE9). The problem is that the input event only fires when adding text to the input and not when deleting (with delete key, cut, right click, etc).

This is my code (uses jQuery):

```
$input.on('input propertychange', function() {
    if($input.val() == '')
        $placeholder.show();
    else $placeholder.hide();
});
```

I read that this may be a known issue. If so, are there any workarounds?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: use change event instead of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check on special keys you should go with keyup:

http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13)
      console.log('enter!');  
});
```

If you just want to fire an event on any change you should go with the change event:

http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$('input').change(function(){
   //When it changes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `keyup` event.  This checks each time the user releases a key, so it is a pretty consistent check for the pressing of delete and cut key combinations, etc.